# IPTables Logging a Flood of "TCP INCOMPLETE" Messages

Tags: iptables

Currently trying to investigate what appears to be load-related problems with a web server and I've found a flood of logs from IPTables that I don't recognize. They all look like this:

> Feb 26 12:03:52 dop002 warning
>   [2559556.039033] IN=eth1 OUT=
>   MAC=*snip* SRC=88.115.48.62 DST=*snip*
>   LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=54
>   ID=14166 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=5 CODE=1
>   GATEWAY=88.115.48.1 [SRC=*snip*
>   DST=88.115.60.143 LEN=40 TOS=0x00
>   PREC=0x00 TTL=57 ID=42868 DF PROTO=TCP
>   INCOMPLETE [8 bytes] ]

Can anyone tell me what this log line means? There's a ton of them in /var/log/messages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an ICMP Type 5 message.

[RFC 792](http://www.rfc-archive.org/getrfc.php?rfc=792)

> Description
>
> ```
>  The gateway sends a redirect message to a host in the following
>  situation.  A gateway, G1, receives an internet datagram from a
>  host on a network to which the gateway is attached.  The gateway,
>  G1, checks its routing table and obtains the address of the next
>  gateway, G2, on the route to the datagram's internet destination
>  network, X.  If G2 and the host identified by the internet source
>  address of the datagram are on the same network, a redirect
>  message is sent to the host.  The redirect message advises the
>  host to send its traffic for network X directly to gateway G2 as
>  this is a shorter path to the destination.  The gateway forwards
>  the original datagram's data to its internet destination.
>
>  For datagrams with the IP source route options and the gateway
>  address in the destination address field, a redirect message is
>  not sent even if there is a better route to the ultimate
>  destination than the next address in the source route.
>
>  Codes 0, 1, 2, and 3 may be received from a gateway.
> ```